# Spring boot YAML object mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am trying to map the YAML in my spring boot to a Java class, Here is my YAML and Java class

```
--- 
tables: 

  trs_fact_txn_detail: 
    tablespecificparams: 
        expiredinterval: "90d"
        fields: "abc"

  trs_fact_txn_detail_et: 
    tablespecificparams: 
        expiredinterval: "56d"
        fields: "abcdef"



@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = {"${table.config.location}"})
public class RedshiftTableConfig {

    private Map<String, tablespecificparams> tables;

    public Map<String, tablespecificparams> getTables() {
        return tables;
    }

    public void setTables(Map<String, tablespecificparams> tables) {
        this.tables = tables;
    }

    public static final class tablespecificparams {

        String expiredinterval;
        String fields;

        public String getExpiredinterval() {
            return expiredinterval;
        }
        public void setExpiredinterval(String expiredinterval) {
            this.expiredinterval = expiredinterval;
        }
        public String getFields() {
            return fields;
        }
        public void setFields(String fields) {
            this.fields = fields;
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting the two tables mapped. Anyhow the value of tablespecificparameters seems to be null. I had been debugging for a while. How do I map the tablespecificparams here 
?

Comment: @Anthon. I think the question intended is clear here. Not sure why it is voted -1. Anyhow I have explicitly added the question to bring in more clarity

Comment: Thanks for updating. The real reason for why one post is down (or up) voted and others not is often unclear. Especially voting as "not useful" is a very subjective IMO. That people don't have to comment when voting is on the one hand good (prevents most of the revenge votes etc) but on the other hand can be frustrating. I hope your issue gets an acceptable answer. I know YAML, but I haven't used Java since this millennium started, so can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your config file should be like below.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = {"${table.config.location}",prefix = "tables"})
public class RedshiftTableConfig {

private Map<String, tablespecificparams> trs_fact_txn_detail;

public Map<String, tablespecificparams> getTrs_fact_txn_detail() {
    return trs_fact_txn_detail;
}

public void setTrs_fact_txn_detail(Map<String, tablespecificparams> trs_fact_txn_detail) {
    this.trs_fact_txn_detail = trs_fact_txn_detail;
}

public static final class tablespecificparams {

    String expiredinterval;
    String fields;

    public String getExpiredinterval() {
        return expiredinterval;
    }
    public void setExpiredinterval(String expiredinterval) {
        this.expiredinterval = expiredinterval;
    }
    public String getFields() {
        return fields;
    }
    public void setFields(String fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
     }
   }
}
```

And yaml file should have properly spaced entries.

```
tables: 

 trs_fact_txn_detail: 
    tablespecificparams: 
         expiredinterval: "90d"
         fields: "abc"

 trs_fact_txn_detail_et: 
        tablespecificparams: 
        expiredinterval: "56d"
        fields: "abcdef"
```

Comment: This wont match with my yaml. I have multiple tables declared trs_fact_txn_detail, trs_fact_txn_detail_et and the code here maps only to one table.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by removing the string "bankspecificparams" from the yaml.

```
--- 
tables: 

  trs_fact_txn_detail: 
        expiredinterval: "90d"
        fields: "abc"

  trs_fact_txn_detail_et:  
        expiredinterval: "56d"
        fields: "abcdef"
```